# How to simplify jQuery code

Tags: jquery, navigation, sliding

It's my beginnings with jQuery. I made a simple content sliding navigation and it works perfect for me but I've no idea how to simplify my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Sliding content navigation
    var active = ".active"
    $('a.europa').click(function () {
        $(active).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
        $('#europa-view').delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
        $('#italia-view, #emilia-view').removeClass('active');
        $('#europa-view').addClass('active');        
    });

    $('a.italia').click(function () {
        $(active).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
        $('#italia-view').delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
        $('#europa-view, #emilia-view').removeClass('active');
        $('#italia-view').addClass('active');
    });

    $('a.emilia').click(function () {
        $(active).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
        $('#emilia-view').delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
        $('#europa-view, #italia-view').removeClass('active');
        $('#emilia-view').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92HXT/267/)
​

Comment: Who voted to close as off-topic? This is no such thing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Javascript:

```
// Sliding content navigation
var active = ".active"
$('a.sharedClass').click(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    $(active).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500).removeClass('active');

    $('#' + name).delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500)
                 .addClass('active');
});​
```

​
New HTML for your list:

```
<div id="view-navigator">
    <ul id="view-list">
        <li class="europa"><a href="#" class="europa sharedClass" name="europa-view">europa</a></li>
        <li class="italia"><a href="#" class="italia sharedClass" name="italia-view">italia</a></li>
        <li class="emilia"><a href="#" class="emilia sharedClass" name="emilia-view">emilia-romagna</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Tbrvv/

Comment: Thanks so much ! It's exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying your code to use class. See below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/92HXT/272/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Sliding content navigation
    var active = ".active"
    $('a.showcontent').click(function() {
        $(active).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
        $('.news-list').removeClass('active');
        $('#' + this.name).delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500)
                          .addClass('active');
    });

});
```

With some markup changes as below,

```
    <ul id="view-list">
        <li class="europa"><a href="#" class="europa showcontent" name="europa-view">europa</a></li>
        <li class="italia"><a href="#" class="italia showcontent" name="italia-view">italia</a></li>
        <li class="emilia"><a href="#" class="emilia showcontent" name="emilia-view">emilia-romagna</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: @Neal lol.. not really.. just formatting. Still we have 1 difference each.. `this.name` and the use of `.active`

Comment: What did I do? I reformatted the same way ^_^ and my 2nd answer was posted 24 seconds before yours :-P

Comment: @Neal Oh I think you had `$('#' + name).addClass('active')` earlier :P well it doesn't matter as long as the answers are different.

Comment: Haha. I realized there was no reason to repeat selecting `$('#' + name)` so I merged it into one.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function which will get id of element which need to show and on click you need only run that function with id you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var active = ".active";

  var clickEvent = function (itemToShow){
    $(active).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
    $('#italia-view, #emilia-view, #europa-view').removeClass('active');
    $(itemToShow).delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
    $(itemToShow).addClass(itemToShow);
  }

  $('a.italia').click(clickEvent("#italia-view"));
  $('a.europa').click(clickEvent("#europa-view"));
  $('a.emilia').click(clickEvent("#emilia-view"));
}
```